# How do I combine AND & OR in a Regex statement?

Tags: regex

I need to create a regex that is true if (as an example):

The word being analyzed contains: red OR green OR blue OR orange; AND
The word being analyzed does not contain: animal

So:

red dog is TRUE
red is TRUE
red animal is FALSE

I know how to use a pipe for the "OR" but I can't figure out the AND?

Answer (score 2):

just use lookaheads:

```
(?=.*(red|green|blue|orange))(?!.*animal).*
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/Z5LQws/2)

Comment: (?!xxx) is a "negative" look ahead.